# Convert Expression to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, expression

Is that possible to convert `Expression` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` if instance of Expression was created on `T` ?

At the end I have list `List<Expression>` and need to produce on `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` where each expression of `List<Expression>` is agregated with `AND`.

Comment: Shouldn't the arguments to be a `List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>`?

Comment: no, I use Kendo Grid, where DataSourceRequest.Filters.Select(x=>) x has only one method CreateExpression and it returns Expresssion Type

Comment: Ok, but still `if instance of Expression was created on T` means that every expression in the list should be cast-able to `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`?

Comment: It should and that is my question how to do it.

Comment: @kosnkov Without knowing what the actual input expressions are, there's no possible way to know how to convert them into what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; just call `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(..., parameter)`, where `...` is an expression composed of the expressions you want to combine.

You'd probably want `list.Aggregate(Expressions.AndAlso)`.

If your expressions don't all share the same `ParameterExpression`, you'll need to rewrite them to do so. (use `ExpressionVisitor`)

Comment: #SLaks Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(..., parameter) what parameter is then ?

Comment: @kosnkov: The `Expression.Parameter(typeof(T))` that you want your expressions to use.

Comment: @SLaks I tried this one, and when query is materiaized I got exception with additional information "The parameter "was not bound in the specyfic LINQ to Entities query expression "

Comment: @SLaks and I create this expression with Kendo extension this way: dataSourceRequest.Filters.Select(x=>x.CreateFilterExpression(Expression.Paramete‌​r(typeof(T)))).ToList()

Comment: @kosnkov: You need to change that to use a single parameter expression instance.

Comment: @SLaks can you elaboreate at least one sentence more, what should I do ?

Comment: @kosnkov: Create a single `Expression.Parameter(typeof(T))`, then pass it to all of the clauses and to the `Lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but every expression in the list must actually be a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instance.

**EDIT:** It turns out that you use [Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor.CreateFilterExpression](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc/ifilterdescriptor) which actually builds a `MethodCallExpression`s.

The following helper method should do the job (works with both lambda and method call expressions):

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var body = expressions[0].GetPredicateExpression(item);
        for (int i = 1; i < expressions.Count; i++)
            body = Expression.AndAlso(body, expressions[i].GetPredicateExpression(item));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
    }

    static Expression GetPredicateExpression(this Expression target, ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        var lambda = target as LambdaExpression;
        var body = lambda != null ? lambda.Body : target;
        return new ParameterBinder { value = parameter }.Visit(body);
    }

    class ParameterBinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression value;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node.Type == value.Type ? value : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable do cast, my List<expression> is created this way: dataSourceRequest.Filters.Select(x=>x.CreateFilterExpression(Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)))).ToList()

Comment: What really returns `CreateFilter`? Show some sample implementation. Or when the cast fails, what is the **actual** type of the expression that you are unable to cast?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type (here is type of Expression<Func<T, bool>>)

Comment: @kosnkov Ok, I think I got the case. You can try the update answer, unfortunately can't test it (don't have Kendo environment).

Comment: Solution from SLaks works, but I really appreciate your help, thank you very much